# Unknown value during simulation Carry Look Ahead with CMOS

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I'm new to Verilog.
 
 I've been assigned to write a 4-bit CLA using pmos and nmos primitives.
 
 I found a website which details the schematic: [Design of VLSI Systems](http://lad.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/epfl/ch06.html)
 
 The CLA is at 6.5.3. I'm using the static implementation.
 
 Starting from the schematic for wire c4, I designed 3 more schematics to calculate the values of wires c1, c2 and c3.
 
 I'm pasting my code:

```
module carryCMOS(a, b, c_in, sum, c_out);
    // variables
    input [3:0] a, b;
    input c_in;
    output [3:0] sum;
    output c_out;

    // VDD and GND
    supply1 vdd;
    supply0 gnd;

    // internal wires
    wire g0, g1, g2, g3;
    wire p0, p1, p2, p3;
    wire c1, c2, c3, c4;

    // for wire c4
    wire pw_c41, pw_c42, pw_c43, pw_c44;
    wire nw_c41, nw_c42, nw_c43, nw_c44;

    // for wire c3
    wire pw_c31, pw_c32, pw_c33;
    wire nw_c31, nw_c32, nw_c33;

    // for wire c2
    wire pw_c21, pw_c22;
    wire nw_c21, nw_c22;

    // for wire c1
    wire pw_c11;
    wire nw_c11;

    // carry look ahead formulas
    assign g0 = a[0] & b[0];
    assign g1 = a[1] & b[1];
    assign g2 = a[2] & b[2];
    assign g3 = a[3] & b[3];

    assign p0 = a[0] ^ b[0];
    assign p1 = a[1] ^ b[1];
    assign p2 = a[2] ^ b[2];
    assign p3 = a[3] ^ b[3];

    // c4
    pmos pm1_c4(c4, vdd, p3);
    pmos pm2_c4(c4, pw_c41, p2);
    pmos pm3_c4(c4, pw_c42, p1);
    pmos pm4_c4(c4, pw_c43, p0);
    pmos pm5_c4(pw_c41, vdd, g3);
    pmos pm6_c4(pw_c42, pw_c41, g2);
    pmos pm7_c4(pw_c43, pw_c42, g1);
    pmos pm8_c4(pw_c44, pw_c43, g0);
    pmos pm9_c4(c4, pw_c44, c_in);

    nmos nm1_c4(c4, gnd, g3);
    nmos nm2_c4(c4, nw_c41, g2);
    nmos nm3_c4(c4, nw_c42, g1);
    nmos nm4_c4(c4, nw_c43, g0);
    nmos nm5_c4(nw_c41, gnd, p3);
    nmos nm6_c4(nw_c42, nw_c41, p2);
    nmos nm7_c4(nw_c43, nw_c42, p1);
    nmos nm8_c4(nw_c44, nw_c43, p0);
    nmos nm9_c4(c4, nw_c44, c_in);

    // c3
    pmos pm1_c3(c3, vdd, p2);
    pmos pm2_c3(c3, pw_c31, p1);
    pmos pm3_c3(c3, pw_c32, p0);
    pmos pm4_c3(pw_c31, vdd, g2);
    pmos pm5_c3(pw_c32, pw_c31, g1);
    pmos pm6_c3(pw_c33, pw_c32, g0);
    pmos pm7_c3(c3, pw_c33, c_in);

    nmos nm1_c3(c3, gnd, g2);
    nmos nm2_c3(c3, nw_c31, g1);
    nmos nm3_c3(c3, nw_c32, g0);
    nmos nm4_c3(nw_c31, gnd, p2);
    nmos nm5_c3(nw_c32, nw_c31, p1);
    nmos nm6_c3(nw_c33, nw_c32, p0);
    nmos nm7_c3(c3, nw_c33, c_in);

    // c2
    pmos pm1_c2(c2, vdd, p1);
    pmos pm2_c2(c2, pw_c21, p0);
    pmos pm3_c2(pw_c21, vdd, g1);
    pmos pm4_c2(pw_c22, pw_c21, g0);
    pmos pm5_c2(c2, pw_c22, c_in);

    nmos nm1_c2(c2, gnd, g1);
    nmos nm2_c2(c2, nw_c21, g0);
    nmos nm3_c2(nw_c21, gnd, p1);
    nmos nm4_c2(nw_c22, nw_c21, p0);
    nmos nm5_c2(c2, nw_c22, c_in);

    // c1
    pmos pm1_c1(c1, vdd, p0);
    pmos pm2_c1(pw_c11, vdd, g0);
    pmos pm3_c1(c1, pw_c11, c_in);

    nmos nm1_c1(c1, gnd, g0);
    nmos nm2_c1(nw_c11, gnd, p0);
    nmos nm3_c1(c1, nw_c11, c_in);

    // sum and carry
    assign sum[0] = p0 ^ c_in;
    assign sum[1] = p1 ^ (!c1);
    assign sum[2] = p2 ^ (!c2);
    assign sum[3] = p3 ^ (!c3);

    assign c_out = !c4;

endmodule

module test_carry;
    reg [3:0] in1, in2;
    wire [3:0] out;
    reg c_in;
    wire c_out;
    carryCMOS carry(in1, in2, c_in, out, c_out);

    initial begin
        $dumpfile("carry.vcd");
        in1 = 4'd0;
        in2 = 4'd1;
        assign c_in = 0;
        #20;
        $display("time:%d in1:%d in2:%d c_in:%d out:%d c_out:%d", $time, 
            in1, in2, c_in, out, c_out);
        #20;
        in1 = 4'd7;
        in2 = 4'd8;
        assign c_in = 1;
        #20;
        $display("time:%d in1:%d in2:%d c_in:%d out:%d c_out:%d", $time, 
            in1, in2, c_in, out, c_out);
        #20;
        in1 = 4'd5;
        in2 = 4'd1;
        assign c_in = 1;
        #20;
        $display("time:%d in1:%d in2:%d c_in:%d out:%d c_out:%d", $time, 
            in1, in2, c_in, out, c_out);
        #20;
        in1 = 4'd5;
        in2 = 4'd10;
        assign c_in = 0;
        #20;
        $display("time:%d in1:%d in2:%d c_in:%d out:%d c_out:%d", $time, 
            in1, in2, c_in, out, c_out);
        $dumpvars(0, carry);
    end

endmodule
```

The problem I have been facing is that when I simulate the model, I'm getting an unknown value at the sum for one of the test inputs.
 [Simulation](http://postimg.org/image/x31irk4c3/)

Comment: If you are getting an unknown for an output bit, determine which transistors are driving that bit and check the values on their gates. Repeat until the problem becomes obvious.

Comment: @JoeHass
I'm guessing that one of the transistors of the c1 wire are causing the problem.
How to view the values on the transistors gates? I'm using ModelSim PE Student Edition 10.3.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know ModelSim but there must be a way to look at the internal nodes connected to the transistors that make c1.

Comment: @JoeHass
I'm getting high impedance values on both pw_c11 and nw_c11 wires. Maybe that is the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following lines:

```
pmos pm1_c1(c1, vdd, p0);
```

The value of `p0` at time 80 is low. Therefore the nmos is trying to drive `c1` to high.

On the other hand:

```
nmos nm1_c1(c1, gnd, g0);
```

The value of `g0` at time 80 is high. Therefore the nmos is trying to drive `c1` to low.

Since `c1` has two drivers of values `1` and `0`, its true value is unknown, i.e. `x`.

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure if this design is correct. You are to convert c1=g0+p0.c0 to a CMOS netlist. Converting a Boolean equation to a CMOS netlist is very trivial. Here are some good references: http://cs.utexas.edu/users/fussell/cs310/lectures/cs310-lecture3.pdf and http://acipo.com/blog/cmos-design-intro

Looking at your code for C1 more closely, you got the NMOS part right. The PMOS network is just the dual of NMOS, that means pm1_c1 should have the same gate (i.e. control) signal as nm1_c1. Just change it, and it should fix the problem at least for C1!

Comment: Okay, I understand the problem. Should I declare a temp wire for all
nmos switches, then combine the results somehow?
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: @Dan Sorescu: I'm not sure if this design is correct. You are to convert `c1=g0+p0.c0` to a CMOS netlist. Converting a Boolean equation to a CMOS netlist is very trivial. Here are some good references: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/fussell/cs310/lectures/cs310-lecture3.pdf and http://acipo.com/blog/cmos-design-intro/

Comment: Looking at your code for C1 more closely, you got the NMOS part right. The PMOS network is just the dual of NMOS, that means `pm1_c1` should have the same gate (i.e. control) signal as `nm1_c1`. Just change it, and it should fix the problem at least for C1!

Comment: That website proved useful. Only thing I need to add is that the output is inverted, meaning in order to get the correct result for each bit of the sum, the value of each `c` wire must be inverted.
I've already done the `c1` and `c2` wire.
I'll report back with the results of my work. :-)